# Upload video with multer and cloudinary - can't read req.file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, multer, cloudinary

In my Mern-Stack I have build a fileuploader using multer and cloudinary. The upload of images works really fine, but when I tried to upload a video, the console told me:

> Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

In the meantime, I've modified my backend and get instead:

> Cannot read property "headers" of undefined

So now I console.log() my headers, and get back the correct headers out of my http-request:

> {"x-powered-by":"Express","access-control-allow-origin":"*","content-type":"application/json;
> charset=utf-8","content-length":"2","etag":"W/"2-vyGp6PvFo4RvsFtPoIWeCReyIC8""}

An error is not shown anymore, instead I see an empty border in my dashboard. But nothing is uploaded.
That is my current backend:

```
const upload = require("../utils/multer");
const cloudinary = require("../utils/cloudinary");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const onHeaders = require("on-headers");
function responseDebugger() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.getHeaders()))
  }
//create
router.post("/", (req,res,next)=>{
    onHeaders(res, responseDebugger)
    res.json({})
})
router.post("/", verifyTokenAndAuthorization, async (req,res)=>{
    function fileupload(req,res,next){
        const uploadVideo = upload.single("src");
    uploadVideo(req,res, function(err){
        if(err instanceof multer.MulterError){
            console.log(err);
        } else if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        next();
    })
}
fileupload();
try{
    const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload_large(req.file.path, {
        upload_preset: "Mern_redux-practice",
        resource_type: "video",
    }
    );
    const newVideos= new Videos({
        cloudinary_id: result.public_id,
        ressort: req.body.ressort,
        theme: req.body.theme,
        title:req.body.title,
        src: result.secure_url,
    })
    const savedVideos= await newVideos.save();
    res.status(200).json(savedVideos);
} catch(error){
    res.status(403)
    console.log(error)
    throw new Error("Action failed");
}
});
```

That is my multer storage:

```
const maxSize = 5 * 1024 *1024;
 const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination:(req,file, callback)=>{
            callback(null,  path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'frontside/public/uploads'));
        },
        fileName: (req, file, callback)=>{
            callback(null, Date.now()+ "--"+ path.extname(file.originalname));
            console.log(req.file)
        },
    })

const upload = multer({
    storage:storage,
    fileFilter:(req,file,callback)=>{
        if(
            file.mimetype == "image/png"||
            file.mimetype == "image/jpg" ||
            file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" ||
            file.mimetype == "video/mp3" ||
            file.mimetype == "video/mp4"
        ){
            callback(null, true);
        } else{
            callback(null,false)
            return callback(new Error("Only .png, .jpg, .jpeg, .mp3, .m4 allowed"))
        }
    },
    limits:{fileSize: maxSize}
});
```

I could imagine that it's some kind of time problem. I had my FormData displayed all the way from the frontend via the redux slice and redux service. Everywhere the field "src" is a file with the correct name of the video.
I add my http-request:

```
const createVideos = async (videosData, token)=>{
    if(videosData){
        for(let value of videosData){
            console.log(value);
        }
    }
    const config = {
        headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        token: `Bearer ${token}` 
        }
    }
    const response = await axios.post(API_URL, videosData, config);
    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data;
}
```

Comment: Hey Roman, I would suggest logging the response from the servers on the upload call to determine what exactly is happening. Without knowing if the call even reached Cloudinarys servers we wouldn't be able to determine the point of failure in the request. Since the asset isn't appearing in Cloudinary, it seems like there's no request being made at all and the upload is failing but it might be making it in to the Browser ( since you are seeing the description ). Show the response messages so we can see where it's failing.

Comment: Hey Ranson, thank you for your answer. I have now done what you said. And I found out that multer did not recognize the field name. I googled this and found out that when I work with Formdata, the  field name has to be the same everywhere, so not just the name of the input and the name I give to multer. I have adjusted this for this reason.But when I send the data, the page starts to load but then breaks off and reloads the entire dashboard. The Redux developer tools say first pending and then undefined. The log of data is correct, Cloudinary shows no bad request. So it must be multer.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help but for videos does uploading using buffer via upload_stream help, see https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007581379-Correct-way-of-uploading-from-buffer-

Comment: do you have github repo?

Comment: @Yilmaz I don't have a git-repo for this project, as it is the final exam of my Mern course.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go through your schemas, where you can define it as object and use mongoDB to save them and then fetch

```
filesForVideo: [Object],
```

below is your example:

```
const addVideo = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let filesArray = [];
    req.files.forEach((element) => {
      const file = {
        fileName: element.originalname,
        filePath: element.path,
        fileType: element.mimetype,
      };
      filesArray.push(file);
    });

    const videoData= new Video({
      ressort: req.body.ressort,
        theme: req.body.theme,
        title:req.body.title,,
      filesForVideo: filesArray,
    });
    await videoData.save();
    res.status(201).send("Book Uploaded Successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error.message);
  }
};
```

You can fetch it as:

```
  <video width height controls>
    <source src=`
    http://localhost:{yourport}/${videoDetails.files[0].filePath}`
    />
    </video>
```